# Centering text (vertically) inside a textbox using CSS

Tags: html, css, textbox

I'm currently working with a textbox that has a background. I was wondering if it's possible to center text (vertically) inside the textbox.

**important**: it's perfectly centered in firefox. Only IE it writes it too high for some reason. I've tried line-height, padding, and margin. Nothing works. Any ideas?

EDIT: This is my current CSS. I should say that I've tried the margin-top method and it didn't work for me. Also, as I mentioned, this is only for IE. I have IE specific style sheets so no worries.

```
.textValue { color: black; font-size: 12px; font-family: David, sans-serif; }
input { width: 110px; padding: 0 2px; padding-right: 4px; height: 20px; border: solid 1px white; margin-bottom: 0px; background: url(../images/contactTextBg.png) no-repeat top right; }
label { float: right; margin-left: 5px; font-size: 13px; }
```

For IE, I have the following:

```
.textValue { font-size: 14px; }
```

as for HTML:

```
            <tr>
                <td><label for="name">name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="textValue" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
```

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: When you say "textbox" do you mean <input type="text/>?

Comment: Show us what you have in terms of CSS so we can take a look...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I wonder how you are able to align the text in a textbox but since you say, here is the suggestion:*

For idiot IE, you can  use this IE specific hack:

```
margin-top:50px; /* for standard-compliant browsers */
*margin-top:50px; /* for idiot IE */
_margin-top:50px; /* for idiot IE */
```

You might want to try other similar properties if you want rather than `margin-top`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I ended up using padding-top and setting it on "input". That seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Sarfraz: would you mind removing your hate'y comments concerning IE? They don't add any value to your answer, quite on the contrary. **idiot IE** three times in one post - this bugged me a lot while reading this answer and it shouldn't be like that on stackoverflow, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try?:

```
input {vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: Yes I tried vertical-align. I fixed it using padding-top and applying it to "input" selector. Thanks though!

Comment: NP, that would've been my first guess, but I thought you said you tried it but it looks like you had just tried margin, sorry ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know this one's a bit old, but I've just run into the same problem.  The solution given here didn't help me which seemed strange.  In my case it was the line height that was set to "1em".  Changing the line height to something that resembled the height of the text box, rather than the size of the font it contained was the solution.  This also continues to function as expected in Firefox, etc.

Comment: Interesting...I remember trying `line-height` and having it not working. Glad it worked for you :)