# vertically centering the text inside a label

Tags: css

The example below works in Chrome but not in FF or IE. I'm trying to vertically center 'Option 1' and 'Option 2'. Can someone push me in the right direction?

**HTML**

```
<div id="polls-4" class="wp-polls">
    <form id="polls_form_4" class="wp-polls-form" action="/sandbox/our-girls/" method="post">
        <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" id="poll_4_nonce" name="wp-polls-nonce" value="eeb4f4642f"></p>
        <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="poll_id" value="4"></p>
        <div id="polls-4-ans" class="wp-polls-ans"><ul class="wp-polls-ul">
        <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-13" name="poll_4" value="13"> <label for="poll-answer-13"><img src="http://i.minus.com/iCKua5u7mVHHA.gif">Option 1</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-14" name="poll_4" value="14"> <label for="poll-answer-14"><img src="http://i.minus.com/iCKua5u7mVHHA.gif">Option 2</label></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wp-polls-ul { margin:0 !important }
.wp-polls-ul li { margin-bottom:10px }
.wp-polls-form .wp-polls-ul li input { float:left;height:35px;margin-right:10px }
.wp-polls-form .wp-polls-ul li label { display:block;height:35px;line-height:35px;vertical-align:top }
.wp-polls-form .wp-polls-ul li label img { margin-right:10px }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tePwt/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering text (vertically) inside a textbox using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432200/centering-text-vertically-inside-a-textbox-using-css)

Comment: I tried the solution in that thread but unfortunately couldn't get it to work.

Comment: vertical centering in css has always been ugly, because the W3C seems to think everything in the universe is horizontal only.

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/tePwt/3/ ?

Comment: @Passerby perfect thank you! If you want to submit your answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

submitted by @Passerby will generate bullets for Firefox, try this with just little modification. [http://jsfiddle.net/tePwt/5/]

Answer (score 0):

@John use  this jsfiddle.net/tePwt/7/ i hope this will help for u.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from comment:

Add

```css
vertical-align:middle
```

to `img`. [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tePwt/3/).