# asp.net textbox text on IE 10 after apply bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

After apply bootstrap asp.net textbox shows text like this. How to solve this issue? I applied line-height:0. But no effect.[this is  the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywkKQ.jpg)

Comment: try reducing your font size or increase text box size

Comment: add padding to textbox , it might help you .or you can using Css Reset to have same desing in all kind of browser .

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432200/centering-text-vertically-inside-a-textbox-using-css

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya this problem shows only on IE10 not in IE11+. other browsers look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution use this media query for IE 10 textbox text top bottom trim issue.

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
            /* IE9 and IE10 rule sets go here */
            input[type=text] {

                line-height:100%;
                font-size:18px;
                height:18px;
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope your textarea fixed heigh or line height unlikeness font size so you check your css and set height on flow this code :
and try

```
input{ line-height: inherit;
font-size: 30px;
height: 50px;}
```

Comment: the issue still has in IE10

Comment: actually this code my IE10 steel work, when don't work in IE10 then You Write this CSS is: line-height: 30px; Or line-height: 100%; the full hight of textbox.